# async/await nested in cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a basic express router. There is an async call to the database to get an array of data. Then, using this array i am doing another async calls in cycle. But i cant figure out, how to make it work in the order i want it to work.
**Code:**

```
const db = require('../models/index');
const router = require('express').Router();
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  const dataSet = await db.sequelize.models.model1.findAll({
    raw: true,
    include: [{
      model: db.sequelize.models.model2,
    }, {
      model: db.sequelize.models.model3,
      required: true
    }],
    limit: 10,
    order: ['flight_date']
  });

  dataSet.forEach(async (item) => {
    delete item.id;
    const mealQtyP = await db.sequelize.models.model4.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        sampleField: sampleFieldCondition,
      }
    });

    console.log('from cycle'); //but it logged after "shall log after all"
  });

  console.log('shall log after all'); //want it to be logged after all
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What is the order in which you want it to work?

Comment: so that it log "from cycle" n times and then log "shall log after all"

Comment: Can the `sampleFieldCondition` be such that you can run `findAll` once and get all the results with one call, eg. with an `or` operator? It would help reduce load on the DB, execute faster and probably make the code easier to read.

Comment: no, i have to get data for every element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "shall log after all" to be printed *after* every item in `dataSet` has been processed, you can map the dataset items to `Promise`s, and then `await` on `Promise.all()`.

```
await Promise.all(dataSet.map(async (item) => {
    delete item.id;
    const mealQtyP = await db.sequelize.models.model4.findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
            sampleField: sampleFieldCondition,
        }
    });

    console.log('from cycle'); //but it logged after "shall log after all"
}));

console.log('shall log after all'); //want it to be logged after all
```

Because you are passing an async function to `map`, it will return a `Promise`, so the result of `map` is an array of `Promise`s. `Promise.all()` returns a `Promise` that is resolved when all of the original `Promise`s in the array are resolved; therefore, awaiting this `Promise` will wait until each of the items in `dataSet` have been processed.

Modifying this code to actually give you the results:

```
const results = await Promise.all(dataSet.map(async (item) => {
    console.log('from cycle'); //but it logged after "shall log after all"
    delete item.id;
    return db.sequelize.models.model4.findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
            sampleField: sampleFieldCondition,
        }
    });
}));

console.log('shall log after all'); //want it to be logged after all
console.log('here are my results:', results);
```

Comment: i want it to make all of the async calls in cycle, which is iterating through elements of dataSet, then grab all of the results of these calls together, map then onto some array, and then to be able to work with this array

Comment: Correct approach, @laptou - just make sure you actually return the `findAll` Promise from within the `map` call, though, e.g.

    const mealQtyP = await Promise.all(
        dataSet.map(async (item) => {
            delete item.id;
            return db.sequelize.models.model4.findAll({
                raw: true,
                where: {
                    sampleField: sampleFieldCondition
                }
            });
        });
    )
    // `mealQtyP` is an array of all the `findAll` results

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov like that?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa fixed

Comment: no, i need the result of every async call from the cycle to be added to the every item, this cycle is iterating through

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov May I suggest that you try again to state your question as clearly as possible? Thanks!

Comment: @laptou i am sorry, i think i ve got ur idea, it is working now, thank you very much!